# How can I export a scene or a model to GLTF Format in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, 3d, three.js, gltf

I'm building a Web App using Meteor that exports the scene to **GLTF** format to the server, is it possible ?

Comment: Do you need to have your glTF scene _generated by_ the server, when visitors make a request to your app? Or would it be OK to generate the glTF scene in advance, and to upload the `.gltf` scene(s) to your server, so that you can use the scene in your web app later?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for [is this example](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_exporter_gltf.html).

For the server side part, as long as you don't use elements that require a browser (e.g `THREE.WebGLRenderer()`) you should be able to run `THREE` on a server. [This is a cool example of that using a Node server](https://gist.github.com/mattdesl/4d9b85e9cc0816f23e553dd670a767bc).

Answer (score 0):

Possible, yes. Has someone written JavaScript code yet that makes exporting glTF easy from web apps created with Three.js? I'm not sure.

Web apps that generate glTF typically use a native component such as [COLLADA2GLTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/COLLADA2GLTF) or [FBX-glTF](https://github.com/cyrillef/FBX-glTF) running as a server side process, like in this example: https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using GLB rather than GLTF because GLTF files contain a reference to external files such as textures(.png files) and animations(.bin files), whereas in the case of GLB all those files are combined into one file. This means that the .glb file contains the textures as well as the animations.

If you want to dig deeper into the whole discussion about gltf vs glb, this link might be useful - https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/1117

You can export a THREE.js scene into GLB format using the below code

```
const btn = document.getElementById('download-glb')
btn.addEventListener('click',download)

function download(){
    const exporter = new GLTFExporter();
    exporter.parse(
        scene,
        function (result) {
            saveArrayBuffer(result, 'ThreejsScene.glb'); 
        },
        { 
            binary: true
        }
    );
}

function saveArrayBuffer(buffer, filename) {
    save(new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), filename);
}
   
function save(blob, filename) {
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);    
    link.download = filename;
    link.click(); // This step makes sure your glb file gets downloaded
    sendFileToBackend(blob, filename)
}

function sendFileToBackend(blob, filename){
    const endpoint = "YOUR_BACKEND_URL_HERE";
    const formData = new FormData();

    let sceneFile= new File([blob], "ThreejsScene.glb");
    console.log(sceneFile)
    formData.append("file", sceneFile);

    const options = {
        method:'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: formData,
    }

    fetch(endpoint,options)
        .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

}
```